# How do I set a local variable to the returned value from an execute in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exec, local-variables

In the following code I'm trying to set a local variable to what is returned from an execute statement in TSQL.

A variable declared: `@id`
The the execute takes a type, and an increment amount,  and returns a value
The desired outcome is to set the value of what is returned to the variable @id

The select statement below shows `@id` as 0 and the execute appears to be returning the value but not setting it to @id. Researching/googling states this is how I should set a local variable to what the execute statement returns but I'm clearly not doing it right.

```
declare @id int = -1 
exec @id = AP_GET_NEXTID @type = 'CT', @increment = 1
print @id
select @id
```

Next ID seems to be returned but not set to @id field.

[image]

Comment: You need to use an INSERT #TempTable EXEC in order to get the results from the PROC.

Then you can select the value into your variable

Comment: Consider returning the NextID value as an output parameter instead of result set. That will make your live easier.

Comment: @DanGuzman where can I find syntax for output parameter rather then result set? I guess that is what I thought I was doing.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) shows the syntax. If you add an output parameter named `@NextId` to the proc, call it like `EXEC AP_GET_NEXTID @type = 'CT', @increment = 1, @NextId =  @id OUTPUT;` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like ...

```
CREATE TABLE #Result ( NextID int )

DECLARE @id int

INSERT #Result exec AP_GET_NEXTID @type = 'CT', @increment = 1

SELECT TOP 1 @id = NextID FROM #Result

PRINT @id

SELECT @id
```

Comment: thank you. Is this something new I am almost certain in the past I was able to declare a variable and set it equal to what get returned from an execute statement or function. Is this a change in the processing or language.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR ... The return value or a PROC is dictated by the RETURN statement in the PROC. Not by a SELECT result. If the PROC selected the result and returned it, that would work fine. Since it's a query result, you have to use this method. The question is ... can you change the PROC you are calling? If so, you can use an output parameter or return the value directly.

Comment: [Return is for status / error codes, not for data](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-or-return-instead-of-output). If you can change the procedure, please use an output parameter, not the RETURN statement.

Comment: @AaronBertrand based on the link why can't i just write EXEC hr = sys.sp_columns table_name = N'dbo.bar'; why wouldn't that work (i had to remove the at symbols from the execute or it wouldn't let me post the comment)

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Because `RETURN` doesn't do what you think it does. What do you think will (or want to) end up in a single variable `@hr` when you call `EXEC @hr = sys.sp_columns @table_name = N'dbo.bar';` for a table with three columns? What do you think (or want) SQL Server to store in that single integer? Hint: the return statement from that stored procedure returns information about success (`0`)/failure(`<error code>`), not any information about your table or any of the columns in it.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR Also to include `@` sign (or to make anything look like code) you enclose the string in `backticks` (``).